# Match the "value" of all "object"s in a string of the form `.. "object":"value" ..` in C++11

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Suppose you've got a JSON-like grammar and you want to match the "value" of all "anyObject"s in a string of the form `.. "anyObject":"value" ..`.

You may think you will be happy with `(?<="anyObject":")[^"]*`. However, `<regex>` doesn't support look-behinds. So, what can you do?

Comment: The default regex dialect ([modified ECMAScript](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript)) supports negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

### Select all values

If you want to capture all values, you can just use:

```
:"(.*?)"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX1uU2/1)**

And then access to the capturing group content.

[image]

But, If you don't want to capture empty content you can use:

```
:"(.+?)"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX1uU2/4)**

[image]

### Select values for specific key

On the other hand, if you just want to capture the value for `"object"` keys, then you can use this regex:

```
"object":"(.*?)"
   ^--- Use the key you want to look up
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX1uU2/2)**

[image]

Comment: I've edited my question. I think you've misunderstood me, I don't want to match all values, but those who are related to "object"s, e.g. "debugFlag".

Comment: What if you only want to match the value of `"anyObject:value"` if `anyObject` is nested inside two super objects, i.e. `".. "supObject2":[{"supObject1":[{"anyObject:value", ..}, ..]}] .."`?

Comment: @0xbadf00d no matter how nested it is, in the last screenshot I put, you can select the values for the keys you want even though it is nested as you asked. Just change `"object":` for the key you need

Comment: The problem is, that "anyObject"s occur in other super objects than "supObject1", too - and I don't want to match them.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I see. I think regex wouldn't be the best solution for that. You should use a JSON parser or even try a [JSONQuery](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/16/jsonquery-data-querying-beyond-jsonpath/) tool although not sure the availability for C++. Btw, I think you should close this question and open a new one to avoid community misunderstandings.